# Properties of albums in ipad photo library

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

Is there any way to acccess the properties of the Albums synced in ipad photo library.I want to get the names with which the Album is saved in the photo library.Please anyone who have tries this or who have any knowledge in this case ,please help.

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use the ALAssetsLibrary.  This ought to get you moving in the right direction:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];        
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) 
                                 {
                                          if (group == nil) 
                                              return;
                                          //this is the album name
                                          NSLog(@"%@",[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]); 
                                 } 
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) 
                                 {   
                                            //failure code here                                              
                                 }];
```

Comment: say i have 3 albums in my library one is saved photos,others are folder1 and folder2 ,will i be able to retrieve images from folder 1 with this code if i specifically specify to retrieve from folder1

Comment: All that the code I posted will do is print out all the albums to the console.  The ALAssetsLibrary is the route you want to take if you want to retrieve images from any album. Check out [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) for a much more thorough example of how you can get access to those albums.

Comment: In what name is the Albums stored in the photo library

Comment: will it be the name which we specifies