# how to fetch Album list from iphone camera roll

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Properties of albums in ipad photo library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854456/properties-of-albums-in-ipad-photo-library)

I want to take list and details of albums in my application. Whatever albums in iphone camera roll and its images. I want to show same album screen in my application. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ALAsset Library for fetching the photolibrary albums and images.

Sample code for fetching the photolibray groups details.

```
void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
{
    if(result != NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);
    }
};

void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    if(group != nil)
    {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    }
};

    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock: ^(NSError *error)
                     {
                         NSLog(@"Failure");
                     }];
```

Check [AssetsLibrary Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) for more options.

Also you can use [UIImagePicker](http://codezone4.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/ios-uiimagepicker-tutorial/) for displaying the album list and selecting images from it.

Image of `UIImagePicker`:

[image: UIImagePicker image]